# How to run multiple php version in lighttd server at same time?

Tags: php, webserver, fastcgi, lighttpd, server-configuration

I have several php projects which contains several php version such as php 5.6, php 7.0 etc.

Recently, I have installed lighttpd server as a local server. Here is my lighttpd.conf

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_fastcgi",
    "mod_redirect",
#       "mod_rewrite",
)

server.document-root        = "/home/andrew/www/"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

dir-listing.activate = "enable"

include "localhost.81.conf"
```

And `localhost.81.conf` is :

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":81" {
        server.document-root       = "/home/andrew/www7"

}
```

I have installed php5.6-cgi and php7.0-cgi and when fastcgi-php5.6 is enabled, then php 5.6 works and when fastcgi-php7.0 is enabled , then php 7.0 works.

mods fastcgi-php5.6:

```
## Start an FastCGI server for php (needs the php5-cgi package)
fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi5.6",
                "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket",
                "max-procs" => 1,
                "bin-environment" => (
                        "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "4",
                        "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
                ),
                "bin-copy-environment" => (
                        "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
                ),
                "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
        ))
```

and mod fastcgi-php7.0:

```
## Start an FastCGI server for php (needs the php7-cgi package)
fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
        ((
                "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi7.0",
                "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket",
                "max-procs" => 1,
                "bin-environment" => (
                        "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "4",
                        "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
                ),
                "bin-copy-environment" => (
                        "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
                ),
                "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
        ))
```

I can not enable two fastcgi-php at same time.
But I want that port 80 will work with php 5.6 and port 81 will work with php7.0.

Is it possible in lighttpd server ?
What are the configuration of running multiple php version at lighttpd ?

Comment: May be, as long as you can configure virtual hosts.

Comment: @Luis how can I configure virtual host? I am newbie of lighttpd.

Comment: Sorry, out of my scope. Just know some apache but shouldn't be that hard if you ask uncle google :D

Comment: I asked uncle google but did not get good result. I found some result but did not work.
If I use apache2 server instead of lighttpd server, is it possible ?

Comment: Probably, haven't tried myself with 2 different versions of php. Good project to learn anyway ;) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update at your fastcgi-php from conf-available folder.

`$ cd /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/`

Make a backup file:

`$ sudo cp 15-fastcgi-php.conf 15-fastcgi-php.conf.save`

Now open `15-fastcgi-php.conf` and update as like:

`$ sudo vi 15-fastcgi-php.conf` and paste of given below code snippet:

```
    fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
            ((
                    "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi5.6",
                    "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket",
                    "max-procs" => 1,
                    "bin-environment" => (
                            "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "4",
                            "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
                    ),
                    "bin-copy-environment" => (
                            "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
                    ),
                    "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
            ))
    )

    $SERVER["socket"] == ":81" {

    fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
            ((
                    "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi7.0",
                    "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php81.socket",
                    "max-procs" => 1,
                    "bin-environment" => (
                            "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "4",
                            "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
                    ),
                    "bin-copy-environment" => (
                            "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
                    ),
                    "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
            ))
    )

}
```

Now, save and close and enable the mod.

`$ sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php`

Reload and restart the server:

`$ sudo systemctl force-reload lighttpd`

`$ sudo systemctl restart lighttpd`

I hope it will work.